# Gdb skips source code lines while debugging assembler program for ARM7 microcontroller

Tags: gcc, assembly, gdb, arm

I have a problem with debugging a simple program written with assembler language for ARM7 microcontroller (AT91SAM7S64). I use gcc, gdb and OpenOCD.
My program is loaded to target correctly and works just fine (it blinks a led). But gdb skips through certain source code lines when i invoke 'next' command.

Here is a fragment of source code:

```
    Reset_Handler:

                LDR     R0, =0x0100
                LDR     R1, =PIOA_PER
                STR     R0, [R1]

                LDR     R1, =PIOA_OER
                STR     R0, [R1]
uuu:
                bl      wait;
                LDR     R1, =PIOA_SODR
                STR     R0, [R1]
uuu1:
                bl      wait;
                LDR     R2, =PIOA_CODR
                STR     R0, [R2]
                b       uuu;
@ one second delay
wait:
    .............
    .............

        .end
```

To get gdb output (see below) i have used "target sim" instead of real target, but rusults are exaclty the same.

```
(gdb) target sim
Connected to the simulator.
(gdb) load
Loading section .text, size 0xc8 vma 0x100000
Start address 0x100000
Transfer rate: 1600 bits in <1 sec.
(gdb) b Reset_Handler
Breakpoint 1 at 0x100064: file main.s, line 59.
(gdb) run
Starting program: C:\Arm\Projects\Asm/./main.elf

Breakpoint 1, Reset_Handler () at main.s:60
60                                      LDR             R1, =PIOA_PER
(gdb) n
61                                      STR             R0, [R1]
(gdb) n
63                                      LDR             R1, =PIOA_OER
(gdb) n
64                                      STR             R0, [R1]
(gdb) n
uuu () at main.s:66
66                                      bl              wait;
(gdb) n
67                                      LDR             R1, =PIOA_SODR
(gdb) n
68                                      STR             R0, [R1]
(gdb) n     <<<<<--------- Here the problem begins
67                                      LDR             R1, =PIOA_SODR
(gdb) n
68                                      STR             R0, [R1]
(gdb) n
67                                      LDR             R1, =PIOA_SODR
(gdb) n
68                                      STR             R0, [R1]
(gdb) stepi <<<<<------ Doing a 'stepi' command allows to pass below 'uuu1' label
uuu1 () at main.s:70
70                                      bl              wait;
(gdb) n
71                                      LDR             R2, =PIOA_CODR
(gdb) n
72                                      STR             R0, [R2]
(gdb) n
73                                      b               uuu;
(gdb) n     <<<<<--------- Here the problem begins again
71                                      LDR             R2, =PIOA_CODR
(gdb) n
72                                      STR             R0, [R2]
(gdb) n
73                                      b               uuu;
(gdb) n
71                                      LDR             R2, =PIOA_CODR
(gdb) where
#0  uuu1 () at main.s:71
#1  0x00100084 in uuu1 () at main.s:70
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
(gdb)
```

It seems like gdb assume 'uuu1' as a separate function and skips it for some reason. If i delete 'uuu1' label the problem disappears. This label is not used anywhere, but gdb behavior looks very strange. I have been trying to find any solution for a long time but with do significant results. Using gcc option '-fomit-frame-pointer' didn't help.
What can i do about it?

Versions of gdb and gcc:

```
arm-none-eabi-gdb --version
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.1
..........
This GDB was configured as "--host=i686-pc-mingw32 --target=arm-none-eabi".

arm-none-eabi-gcc --version
arm-none-eabi-gcc (GCC) 4.5.1
```

My MakeFile:

```
TRGT = arm-none-eabi-
CC   = $(TRGT)gcc
CP   = $(TRGT)objcopy
AS   = $(TRGT)gcc -x assembler-with-cpp
#AS   = $(TRGT)as
LD   = $(TRGT)ld
OBJDUMP = $(TRGT)objdump
LD_SCRIPT = main.ld
MCU      = arm7tdmi

#DEBUG = stabs
DEBUG = dwarf-2
ASFLAGS = -mcpu=$(MCU) -g$(DEBUG)
LDFLAGS = -T $(LD_SCRIPT)

all: main.elf main.lss
    @echo Done!

main.elf : main.o 
    @echo Linking $<
    $(CC) -nostartfiles $(LDFLAGS) $< -o $@

main.o : main.s
    @echo Compiling $<
    $(AS) -c $(ASFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2):

try using "si" instead of n in the problem piece of code.

"n" is more or less next statement, "si" is next asm instruction.

if the debug code for the piece of asm is not correct, "si" might still allow you to step it, taking advantage of the fact that in this case "statement" and "assembler" level are the same.

Comment: Yes, it works (see my comments in gdb log above). But is works as "step into" instead of "step over". I would like gdb to step over 'wait' procedure the same way it do that on the line 66. I plan to use gdb with Eclipse and this is very annoying effect for me.

Comment: Why 'debug code for the piece of asm' could be not correct? Maybe there is any "magic" compatibility argument for gdb or gcc?

Comment: Bugs in gcc I guess.  The debug info does not sync with the lines. Maybe you can try forcing dwarf

Answer (score 0):

Use `ni` instead of `next` and `si` instead of `step` through assembler instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old, but you should try to add the `-O0` flag to the compiler. I prevents gcc of doing any optimization, which can lead to problems like the ones you got.